# Rails - what is the "correct" way to stop accepting requests without breaking those being already processed?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, backup, puma

I need a few seconds for making daily backup of the (Rails 5 with Puma cluster behind nginx reverse-proxy) application's data, which includes both database and filesystem records. The typical Rails backup solutions like backup gem don't seem to be able to handle such case so I imagine the easiest way would be to stop serving clients for those few seconds. This would ensure that all transactions are finished and I get a consistent dataset. But what is the best way to allow requests, which are already being processed to be responded to without interruption, while disallowing any further ones at the same time?

Answer (score 0):

You can check this two, this might help.

[Backup Gem](https://github.com/backup/backup)

[Dumper Gem](https://dumper.io/)

Comment: Thanks - I've seen those and so far haven't found the answer.

Answer (score 0):

@silverdr, I'm not quiet understand what you said, but i wonder that whether the real-time sync function can help you or not. real-time sync is a kind of sync function which enables the data on target location keep up with the data on source location. That is to say, once there is a change made to source files, the related files on target location will immediately updated.

Comment: I am not fully sure I understand you either :-) but my case is that (unless somebody knows a better method) I need to stop responding to requests without interrupting the one(s) that are already being served. Once I know the "correct" way of doing this, I'll handle the rest without problems.